# Error parsing emitter LibGDX ParticleEffects

Tags: java, libgdx, game-development

I am using `LibGDX 1.9.8` and attempting to add `ParticleEffects` made with the `ParticleEditor`.

I try to load a new effect with:

```
torchFX.load(Gdx.files.internal("effects/torch.p"), Gdx.files.internal("effects"));
```

But I am getting the below error

```
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" java.lang.RuntimeException: Error parsing emitter: torch
at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.ParticleEmitter.load(ParticleEmitter.java:1160)
at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.ParticleEmitter.<init>(ParticleEmitter.java:103)
at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.ParticleEffect.newEmitter(ParticleEffect.java:227)
at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.ParticleEffect.loadEmitters(ParticleEffect.java:173)
at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.ParticleEffect.load(ParticleEffect.java:153)
at com.bbg.dc.AssetLoader.getTorchFX(AssetLoader.java:92)
at com.bbg.dc.scenes.GameScene.setupMap(GameScene.java:202)
at com.bbg.dc.scenes.GameScene.switchMap(GameScene.java:159)
at com.bbg.dc.scenes.GameScene.start(GameScene.java:139)
at com.bbg.dc.DCGame.changeScene(DCGame.java:160)
at com.bbg.dc.scenes.MainMenu.buttonPressed(MainMenu.java:33)
at com.bbg.dc.iface.Button.update(Button.java:98)
at com.bbg.dc.iface.Scene.update(Scene.java:180)
at com.bbg.dc.scenes.MainMenu.update(MainMenu.java:49)
at com.bbg.dc.DCGame.render(DCGame.java:129)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:225)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:126)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.ParticleEmitter.SpawnShape.false
at java.lang.Enum.valueOf(Enum.java:238)
at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.ParticleEmitter$SpawnShape.valueOf(ParticleEmitter.java:1637)
at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.ParticleEmitter$SpawnShapeValue.load(ParticleEmitter.java:1622)
at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.ParticleEmitter.load(ParticleEmitter.java:1107)
... 16 more
```

I have already made sure to have the `particle.png` in the effects directory. I have tried it with my own custom particle effect as well as the `ParticleEditor` default. I have tried altering the `SpawnShape` to no avail. I have been coming to SO for answers for years and this is the first problem I couldn't solve by searching. I have also just updated all my jars to latest `1.9.8` and latest version of `ParticleEditor`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

I solved this by running ParticleEditor from the same gdx-tools.jar as my project uses. I assumed the runnable jar in the runnables folder in the libgdx repo was identical, but it is not. You must use the same tools.jar for both.

Comment: Thanks. That was the case for me.

Answer (score 3):

I had a very similar issue, looking at an older file which worked and a newer file I noticed there were a number of entries in the newer one which was not present in the working file.

Namely the line;

```
independent: false
```

Deleting all instances on this seemed to do the trick for me.

I assume it's an updated feature not present in the current stable version of libgdx (1.9.8 at the time of writing). It may be available in the nightly version.

Looks like a property that's been added to the tweens on each individual property.

It would be useful if the older builds of the tools were more easily accessible.

Comment: Thanks for that insight! This will be helpful for converting old particle effects people have shared that I was unable to use in-game but able to see in the particle editor. For the record, the downloadable jar of the 2D particle editor on the libgdx website is outdated, so you have no choice but to run from gdx-tools.jar or source